# Calculation of an "unconstrained" normal distribution (starting from a censored one)

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, conditional-probability, density-function, truncation

Assume that two r.v. $W$ and $Y|W=w$ with

(1) $W \sim \text{N}(\mu_w,\sigma_w^2)$ (iid)

(2) $Y|W=w \sim \text{N}(w,\sigma_y^2)$ (iid)

Further we only observe $Y$ if $Y$ is less then $W$, i.e.,

(3) $Y|Y\le W$

**Goal:** Find the pdf of the censored observations, i.e., of $Y|Y\le W$ and from that deduce the uncensored pdf and the first two moments (so i.m.h.o. we have to find$f_Y(y)$). The first two moments of this uncensored pdf are supposed to depend upon $E(Y|Y\le W)$ and $Var(Y|Y\le W)$.

---

By definition of *conditional pdf* we have that:

(4) $f_{Y|W}(y|W = w)= \frac{f_{Y,W}(y,w)}{f_W(w)}$

Next, the definition of a *truncated density* gives for a abitrary value of $W$:

(5) $ f_{Y|Y\le W}(y|y\le w) = \frac{f_Y(y)}{P(Y\le W)}$

---

I would simply rewrite (4) to

$f_{Y|W}(y|W = w)f_W(w) = f_{Y,W}(y,w)$

then integration over $f_{Y,W}(y,w)$ w.r.t $w$ should yield $f_Y(y)$, i.e.,

(a) $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{Y,W}(y,w) dw = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_Y(y|W = w)f_W(w) dw = f_Y(y)$

Plugin in $f_Y(y)$ into (5), ($P(Y\le W)$ will also be given by $f_Y(y)$) I will se how the moments of $f_{Y|Y\le W}(y|y\le w)$ will look and how the moments of $f_Y(y)$ depend upon them.

So (a) will look like

$f_Y(y) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2_y}}\text{exp}\big(-\frac{(y-w)^2}{2\sigma_y^2}\big)\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2_w}}\text{exp}\big(-\frac{(w-\mu_w)^2}{2\sigma_w^2}\big)dw$

Except for the $w$ in the first $\text{exp}$, this looks very easy but since there is a $w$ im a little bit stuck how to solve this...

Comment: Look up the answer to this question : http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/72857/derivation-of-conditional-distribution-from-other-two-distributions/72870#72870

Comment: Thanks. This might be stuipid but would it not help to center $Y$ w.r.t $W$ then $Z:=Y-W$ will have expectation $0$ and variance $\sigma_y^2$

Comment: Then you should also eliminate $W$ from the second exp which would make $Z$ appear in there too, having again your new integrating variable ($z$) present in the two exp's. You don't gain anything, really.

Comment: Ah sure, thats what I missed. I already presumed that this would not work... Why should centering solve a integral...

Comment: This question was also answered later at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/166273 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. Let's do this, for CV's shake.

First compact by setting $C=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2_y}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2_w}} = \frac{1}{2\pi\sigma_y\sigma_w}$, so

$$f_Y(y) =C \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp\left\{-\frac{(y-w)^2}{2\sigma_y^2}\right\}\exp\left\{-\frac{(w-\mu_w)^2}{2\sigma_w^2}\right\}dw$$

We have 
$$exp\left\{-\frac{(y-w)^2}{2\sigma_y^2}\right\}\exp\left\{-\frac{(w-\mu_w)^2}{2\sigma_w^2}\right\} = 
\exp\left\{-\frac{y^2-2yw+w^2}{2\sigma_y^2}\right\}\exp\left\{-\frac{w^2-2w\mu_w+\mu_w^2}{2\sigma_w^2}\right\} 
=\exp\left\{-\frac{y^2}{2\sigma_y^2}-\frac{\mu_w^2}{2\sigma_w^2}\right\} \exp\left\{-\frac{w^2}{2\sigma_y^2}-\frac{w^2}{2\sigma_w^2}\right\}\exp\left\{\frac{2yw}{2\sigma_y^2}+\frac{2w\mu_w}{2\sigma_w^2}\right\}$$

Setting $s^2\equiv \sigma_y^2+\sigma_w^2$ we arrive at

$$=\exp\left\{-\frac{y^2}{2\sigma_y^2}-\frac{\mu_w^2}{2\sigma_w^2}\right\} \exp\left\{-\frac{s^2}{2\sigma_y^2\sigma_w^2}w^2\right\}\exp\left\{\frac{\sigma_w^2y+\sigma_y^2\mu_w}{\sigma_y^2\sigma_w^2}w\right\}$$

Include the first $\exp$ in the constant, $C^*=C \exp\left\{-\frac{y^2}{2\sigma_y^2}-\frac{\mu_w^2}{2\sigma_w^2}\right\}$.
Set
$$\beta\equiv \frac{s^2}{2\sigma_y^2\sigma_w^2},\qquad \alpha\equiv \frac{\sigma_w^2y+\sigma_y^2\mu_w}{\sigma_y^2\sigma_w^2}$$ to obtain

$$f_Y(y) =C^* \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\beta w^2+\alpha w}dw=C^*\left[ \int_{-\infty}^{0}e^{-\beta w^2+\alpha w}dw + \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\beta w^2+\alpha w}dw\right]$$

$$=C^* \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\beta w^2}\left[e^{-\alpha w}+e^{\alpha w}\right]dw =2C^* \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\beta w^2}\operatorname{cosh}(\alpha w)dw$$

where $\operatorname{cosh}$ is the hyperbolic cosine.

Using a formula provided in Gradshteyn & Ryzhik (2007), "Table of Integrals, Series and Products", 7th ed., p. 384, eq. 3.546(2) we have

$$f_Y(y)=2C^*\frac 12 \sqrt {\frac {\pi}{\beta}} \exp\left\{\frac {\alpha^2}{4\beta}\right\}$$

Now $$\frac {\alpha^2}{4\beta} = \frac {\left(\frac{\sigma_w^2y+\sigma_y^2\mu_w}{\sigma_y^2\sigma_w^2}\right)^2}{4\frac{s^2}{2\sigma_y^2\sigma_w^2}} = \frac {(\sigma_w^2y+\sigma_y^2\mu_w)^2}{2\sigma_y^2\sigma_w^2s^2}$$

and bringing back in $C^*$ (and $\beta$) in all its glory we have

$$f_Y(y)=\frac{1}{2\pi\sigma_y\sigma_w}\exp\left\{-\frac{y^2}{2\sigma_y^2}-\frac{2\mu_w^2}{\sigma_w^2}\right\}\sqrt{\pi} \left(\sqrt {\frac{s^2}{2\sigma_y^2\sigma_w^2}}\right)^{-1} \exp\left\{\frac {(\sigma_w^2y+\sigma_y^2\mu_w)^2}{2\sigma_y^2\sigma_w^2s^2}\right\} $$

The constant terms simplify to

$$\frac{1}{2\pi\sigma_y\sigma_w}\sqrt{\pi} \left(\sqrt {\frac{s^2}{2\sigma_y^2\sigma_w^2}}\right)^{-1} = \frac{1}{s\sqrt{2\pi}} $$

and, the exponentials end up in the normal exponential. So in the end

$$f_Y(y) = \frac{1}{s\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left\{-\frac{(y-\mu_w)^2}{2s^2}\right\}= N(\mu_w, s^2),\qquad s^2\equiv \sigma_y^2+\sigma_w^2$$

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but you have only derived the distribution of $Y$, whereas the OP requires the conditional distribution of $Y$ given $Y \leq W$. Moreover there's no need to do all these calculations in order to derive the distribution of $Y$.

Comment: @Stephane Laurent In the OP's question the solution to the specific integral is requested _at the end_ of OP' post, where the OP clearly indicates that the solution to this integral is what the OP needs. It would be very useful to everybody if you would post an answer with the alternative and shorter way to derive the solution to this integral.

Comment: Ok sorry, I'm at the office and the LaTeX rendering does not work. The shorter way I had in mind is the one given by @RayKoopman, without integral calculations. If you really want to calculate an integral, you don't need to calculate the normalization constant.

Comment: If u've $f_Y(y)$ its not a big effort to derive (5). Nevertheless is there not a small error in the calculation? Since $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \text{exp}\{-\beta w^2 + \alpha w\}dw$ = $\int_{\infty}^0 \text{exp}\{-\beta w^2 - \alpha w\}dw$ + $\int_{0}^\infty \text{exp}\{-\beta w^2 + \alpha w\}dw$ = $-\int_0^{\infty} \text{exp}\{-\beta w^2 - \alpha w\}dw + \int_{0}^\infty \text{exp}\{-\beta w^2 + \alpha w\}dw$. Then I would use Gradshteyn & Ryzhik (2007), "Table of Integrals, Series and Products", 7th ed., p. 336, eq. 3.322(2) with $\alpha = -\gamma$ for the 1st part.

Comment: The formula I used (which makes use of the cosh function) is quicker than what I had proposed to my other answer. Mistake, there isn't, in either ways. Be careful with how signs change/change not when swapping integral limits etc.

Comment: @Stephan Laurent Yes, of course, but I wanted to calculate the _integral_ for which the OP said he was stuck. And the bulk of my calculations are not about the constant term, but about manipulating the terms that contain the integrating variable.

Comment: To calculate the moments, do I rewrite $Y|Y\le W$ to $W+Z|Z\le 0$ and integrate that? I'm not sure which density I'm supposed to use. To derive the moments of a truncated r.v., the usual way is $E(W+Z|Z\le0)=\int_{-\infty}^0 \frac{f_{W+Z}(w+z)}{P(Z\le 0)}dz$. Since $P(Z\le 0)=0.5$ and $f_{W+Z}(w+z)=f_Y(y)$ I'm not sure about the boundarys and what variable is used for integration? For $f_Y(y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi s^2}}\text{exp}\{−\frac{(y−μw)^2}{s^2}\}$ I could also write $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi s^2}}\text{exp}\{−\frac{(w+z−μw)^2}{s^2}\}$ and integrate from $\infty$ to $0$ w.r.t to $z$.

Comment: I would derive the pdf of $Z= Y-W$, and then calculate the moments of the truncated $Z|Z\le 0$.

Comment: Will I not just recieve a pdf which is $Z\sim N(\mu_w,\sigma_w^2)$ by assumption? If I now calculate the moments from $z$ by integrating over $z$, from $-\infty$ to $0$, how do I get some sort of closed form?

Answer (score 2):

$Y = W + Z$, where $Z$ is normal with mean 0 and variance $\sigma_z^2$ and is independent of $W$. (Note that I am using $\sigma_z^2$ where the OP used $\sigma_y^2$, which I reserve for the marginal variance of $Y$.) Then the unconstrained joint distribution of $(W,Y)$ is bivariate normal with $\mu_y = \mu_w$, $\sigma_y^2 = \sigma_w^2 + \sigma_z^2$, and $\sigma_{wy} = \sigma_w^2$.

Letting $\phi$ denote the standard normal pdf, integrating over the halfplane $Z<0$ gets the following marginal moments of $Y\,|\,(Y<W)$:

Mean $= \mu_y = 2 \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^0 (w \sigma_w + \mu_w + z \sigma_z)\,\phi(z)\mathrm{d}z\,\phi(w)\mathrm{d}w = \mu_w - \sigma_z \sqrt{2/\pi}$.

Variance $=\sigma_y^2 = 2 \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^0 (w \sigma_w + \mu_w + z \sigma_z - \mu_y)^2\,\phi(z)\mathrm{d}z\,\phi(w)\mathrm{d}w =  \sigma_w^2 + \sigma_z^2 (1-2/\pi)$.

Third central moment $=2 \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^0 (w \sigma_w + \mu_w + z \sigma_z - \mu_y)^3\,\phi(z)\mathrm{d}z\,\phi(w)\mathrm{d}w = \sqrt{2}(\pi - 4) \sigma_z^3 / \pi^{3/2}$.

Those can be solved in reverse order to get $\sigma_z^2$, then $\sigma_w^2$, then $\mu_w$, which are necessary and sufficient to specify the unconstrained joint distribution.